# New Relic: How to automate creating an APM app id?

Tags: newrelic

Automating the onboarding of new applications to a system, I wonder how to create all necessary data for them, especially the application id, in an automated way:

It seems like onboarding a new application to NewRelic requires me to go through the "Add Data" > select language; for example "Java" > account selection > Begin installation > ..... (an endless list of popups and screens follows). It also seems like I have to specify the application name within the wizard.

The next step would be, to actually deploy the application (this is handled by a pipeline), with all necessary New Relic parameters set as environment variables. It would then start reporting, and only after that, I could grab the application id from the New Relic UI. I need the application id for the REST API call to mark the release.

Documenting all that for a developer to create a new application on a platform sounds like a nightmare. Having to deploy the application to get all data necessary to deploy it, just does not sound right.

Is there an easy (or otherwise recommended) way to onboard a new APM application, ideally via the API? Or a "Create New APM Application" button, that just returns all useful data, including the application id?